# C++ And SQL DATABASE Retrieving Byte of the image

Tags: mysql, c++-cli

I would appreciate help for handling picture byte retrieved from SQL database to byte buffer and stream the buffer to the picturebox in c++?

I tried using the array of byte and it's denying

Below code is whats i tried and i'm getting an exception error say array out of inbound

```
MySqlConnection ^connect = gcnew MySqlConnection("datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = admin; password = 251844; database = datastore");
MySqlCommand ^cmd = gcnew MySqlCommand("SELECT image FROM imagesTbl WHERE image_id = 1;",connect);
MySqlDataReader ^Reader;

try
{
    connect->Open();
    Reader = cmd->ExecuteReader();
    array<System::Byte>^ buffer;
    while (Reader->Read())
    {
        long long store = Reader->GetBytes(1,0,nullptr,0,1);
        buffer = gcnew array<System::Byte>(store);
        Reader->GetBytes(1, 0, buffer, 0, 0);
    }
    pictureBox1->Image = Image::FromStream(gcnew IO::MemoryStream(buffer));
    pictureBox1->Refresh();

}
```

Comment: Please post your [mre] code as text not images and show the full error message you are getting

Comment: `while(true)` ?

Comment: while(dataReader->Read())

Comment: I suspect `Reader->GetBytes(1,0,nullptr,0,1)` should be `Reader->GetBytes(0,0,nullptr,0,0)`